# Как вывести сообщение в инпут?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть условие :

```
      if (!phone || phone.replace(/\D/g, '').length < 12) enable = false;
                 if (codes[phone.substr(5, 3)]) valid = true;
```

Разметка :

```
             <form>
              <div class="column">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ваш    
         телефон" name="phone" data-mask="+38 (099) 999-99-99" required/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
              <div class="form-controls">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-red btn-large btn-block  
        btn-submit" required disabled="disabled">Заказать звонок</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
```

Как мне вывести сообщение «некорректный ввод» в инпут, в случае несоблюдения этих условий?

Вот полный код : [jsfiddle.net/0xL0fctq/31](http://jsfiddle.net/0xL0fctq/31/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (!phone || phone.replace(/\D/g, '').length < 12) enable = false;
if (codes[phone.substr(5, 3)]) {
    valid = true
} else if (enable==true) {
    $('.form-control').val('Некорректный ввод');
}
```

Вот такой код. Я правильно понял суть вопроса? 
Только зачем же выводить в сам инпут? Можно вывести сообщение об ошибке рядом.

Comment: @ Plikard , а как в сообщение вывести ???

Comment: Создайте блок с классом `.hidden {display: none}` содержащий текст ошибки и убирайте класс с помощью `$('#error').removeClass('hidden');` когда необходимо показать ошибку